# Cakephp2 pagination links with routing

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have a problem with routing cakephp.

Here is my code :

```
Router::connect(
    '/find-job/*', 
    array('controller'=>'TblJobs','action'=>'findJob'),
    array('pass' => array( 'id'))
);
Router::connect(
    '/*', 
    array('controller'=>'tbl_jobs', 'action'=>'index'),
    array('pass' => array( 'id'))
);
```

On the first line, it's working normal(`localhost/find-job/page:2`). but on the second line, i have a problem with it.

when i run it, i have some pages: page1 , page2, page3 but the link like : localhost/tbl_jobs/index/page:2

but the link i need : localhost/page:2

I'm sorry because my english is so bad.

Thanks !

Comment: where is the code for generating the pagination links?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Router::connect(
'/:page', 
array('controller'=>'tbl_jobs', 'action'=>'index')
);
```